# How to access a parent's class's static variable in JS?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I have a main static class which starts to become lengthy and hard to read for my comfort. I want to move some of its components (nested static classes) into other files to clean things up.

My problem comes when I move the **User** subclass into a separate file, even when I import the main class into that new file, the **guildServer** static variable from the main class is undefined, despite always being set previously using the **init** I've previously made.

Here's my code:

```js
// corvus.js (main static class)

module.exports = class Corvus{
  // ...
  static guildServer = null;

  static init(callback){
    // Sets guildServer (which is Guild object from Discord.js), is called when starting the program and is always executed before anything else.
  }

  static User = require("path to user.js");

  // ...
  // Other classes I want to move into separate files as well
}
```

```js
// user.js

// Import corvus.js else its parameters are unknown
const Corvus = require('path to corvus.js');

module.exports = class User{
    /**
     * Returns whether a user is a guild member or not.
     * @param {User} userID
     * @returns {Boolean}
     */
    static isMember(user){
        let member = Corvus.guildServer.member(user);
        if(member){
            // Do something
        }
        return false;
    }
    
    // ...
}
```

When I call Corvus.User.isMember('userID'), I get the error "Cannot read property 'member' of undefined" from the isMember() function, which means Corvus.guildmember is undefined when used in user.js.
However, I didn't have this error when the User class was directly nested in the Corvus class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that when you import `Corvus` into your user file, it's importing before any code is executed which means `Corvus.guildServer` is defined as null.

**Here is a quick fix for your problem:**

```js
static isMember(user){
    const Corvus = require('path to corvus.js');

    let member = Corvus.guildServer.member(user);
    if(member){
        // Do something
    }
    return false;
}
```

And you remove the import from the top of the code.